# Docker: environment variable in `VOLUME` instruction?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Let say I have this variable: `ENV MY_DATA="/my/dir/data"`

And then use it as: `VOLUME [$MY_DATA]`

After building image and connecting to container, what I see is this:

[image]

If I add it as `VOLUME ["/my/dir/data"]`, then such artifact directories do not appear. Is there some special syntax I need to use via `VOLUME` so it would render my `ENV` correctly?

Comment: Why are you specifying `MY_DATA` as a relative path? Try prefixing it with a `/`

Comment: @Z4-tier sorry, thats a typo.

Comment: You almost never need `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile, and you almost never need to set paths inside an image as environment variables (since they will be fixed once the image is built and you need them for things like `docker run -v` options).

Comment: Well kind of. That same path is used during runtime as an argument in specific service configuration. Also dont you need VOLUME for paths that must be used to save persistent data, like volumes with local driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick Dockerfile for illustration:

```
FROM busybox
# ARG MY_DATA="/my/dir/data" <- Works too.
ENV MY_DATA="/my/dir/data"
VOLUME $MY_DATA
ENTRYPOINT ls -d /my/dir/data
```

Build the image and run it:

```
docker build -t <tag> .
docker run -t --rm <tag>
/my/dir/data        # list the volume created as expected
- or -
docker run -it --entrypoint "" --rm <tag> sh
ls -d /my/dir/data  # list the volume created as expected
```

Comment: For some reason I thought, only Array of paths was valid. But yes, it seems you can simply specify path without array or multiple paths separated by space.